# How does quest progress work if you skip some via friends' games?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just started in Inferno and joined a friend who was further along in the story.  If I complete quests with him, what will happen to *my* progression?  Will none of what I did with him count cause I missed the intervening quests?

Answer (score 3):

The quest(s) you did with him will count. None of the quests between those you did with your friends and what you've already completed will be effected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and sorry for my horrible english.

Comment: @Marcus No problem :). If you feel it's an adequate answer you should go ahead and mark it as "accepted"